# matplotlib interactive widget layout issue

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In a JupyterLab notebook, when using `%matplotlib widget` with ipywidgets' Select() or SelectMultiple() results in a layout with large space between the chart and widgets. Is there anyway to remove that space, or remove the toolbar?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the toolbar like so:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# whatever plotting code
fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
```

That also looks like it may be bug, you might consider posting an issue on https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl. But be sure to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you do that. (ideally the code shold be small and copy-pasteable